ARRAYFORMULA to autoincrement from previous row but restart from 1 when product changes
I am trying to assign a serial number to each row for the product on that row. So for product 101, I'll have 101-1, 101-2, 101-3... etc. For product 102, it should restart the counter from 1, so I get 102-1, 102-1, 102-3...
I first tried to use arrayformula() to compare the current product ID to the previous row, if it's the same the serial number should be the previous serial number + 1, otherwise it starts from 1. But arrayformula can't seem to compare value of the previous row to the current cell. Then I tried using row(), but it is not possible to reset the serial number.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "",IF(A2:A=A1:A, ROW(A2:A) - ROW(A2) + 1,1))

Please see the spreadsheet:
Spreadsheet link


You may try:
=scan(,A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,if(c<>offset(c,-1,),1,a+1)))


